# Can the rotation speed of a planet be modified by everyone running in the same direction?

Tags: physics

If everyone on a planet (for example on earth) simultaneously started running in the same direction, could the forces of their feet hitting the ground have an impact on how fast it turns? If there would be an effect but it would be negligible, how many people would it take before a day can be shorted by one hour, assuming everyone runs in the same direction for 24 hours straight?

Comment: It makes me remember a funny web project a long time ago, where people would try to jump simultaneously in order to push the planet away. I doubt most people jumped at all nor I don't know if some people who actually jumped did it in opposite to the intended motion. It's very hard to set up, same for running around, especially if you have to run towards the coast and into the water, or considering they should not return to their original location/home, if we follow this same logic and think it might work.

Comment: [Relevant XKCD.](https://what-if.xkcd.com/26/)

Comment: i don't think any measurable difference can be achieved, except if you severely increase human population and replace each one of them by a superman.

Comment: "assuming everyone runs in the same direction for 24 hours straight" -- as soon as they stopped, any change would revert. And you can see that even covering the whole Earth in humans, we'd get a layer about 1.8m tall, less than 1 kg/dm^3 in density; compared with the mass of Earth, that's negligible. And the equatorial velocity of the Earth is some 1600 km per hour.

Comment: Well, when my mother would join in..

Comment: Eventually, we’ll have to stop, you know.

Comment: Added complication for fun: to speed up/shorten the apparent day you'd have to accelerate West and then continue running, but if you're running West your day will *slow down* because your relative position on earth is changing .

Comment: The other [relevant xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/8/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [angular momentum due to the Earth's rotation](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-angular-momentum-of-earth) is about 7.2 × 10<sup>33</sup> kg m<sup>2</sup>s<sup>−1</sup>. There's a rather well-known [XKCD comic](https://xkcd.com/162/) about someone spinning in a counter-clockwise direction, as that decreases the angular momentum (as long as you're spinning) and makes the night last longer. If you want to shorten the day instead, you'll have to spin in a clockwise direction.

But how much momentum can a human generate? Let's model a human body as a solid cylinder, whose [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) is $\frac12mr^2$. Assuming a mass of 80 kg, and a body diameter of 30 centimeter, that would be 0.9 kg m<sup>2</sup>. So if you would be able to make 4 revolutions per second, or $8\pi$ radians per second, you'd have an angular momentum of 22.6 kg m<sup>2</sup>s<sup>−1</sup>. The Earth's population is 7.75 billion, so together we'd be able to generate 1.75 × 10<sup>11</sup> kg m<sup>2</sup>s<sup>−1</sup> angular momentum, which is several orders of magnitude (10<sup>22</sup>) less than Earth's rotation. We wouldn't even be able to measure the difference.

Comment: What if we build trains, instead of running?

Comment: Good first approximation, and you'll lose even more effect according to distribution of people around the globe. For maximum effect, everyone would have to spin at the north pole. People spinning on the equator won't affect the angular momentum around the earth's axis at all, and people in the southern hemisphere would need to spin the other direction.

Comment: @Sonvar:  That or you need to get them all moving at a significant fraction of the equatorial rotation speed of the Earth (about 1600 km/h.)  Don't go too fast, though, or you'll end up in orbit.

Comment: +1, though as a human myself, I feel a bit weird that you refer to a human as "it". :-/

Comment: @ruakh good catch. I thought I had written "human body"...

Comment: We can probably be a little bit more effective by all running East/West as the OP suggests. This means our rotational centre is now the Earth's spin axis, so our moment of inertia gains by about the Earth radius squared (10^12). But then our angular velocity plummets, assuming we reach the same max speed the angular velocity drops by a factor about (neglecting 2pi stuff) 1 Earth radius (10^6).  So I make the overall advantage from running as nearly 6 orders of magnitude. Still nowhere near enough but certainly better.

Comment: The question is about running, not spinning.

Comment: @2012rcampion while I wrote this answer, there was another answer to explain why running wouldn't work. I'm not sure if it's correct, so I focused on a similar method which (I tend to trust Randall Munroe when it comes to things like this) should work.

Answer (score 11):

### You could speed up the rotation, but could not achieve your goal

If everyone started running in one direction, they would impart a negligible but existent amount of extra spin to the planet, but this would not achieve any sustained acceleration of the planet in that direction, only speed it up so that the opposite forces are in equilibrium.  The moment your people stop running, thier breaking force will be imparted back into the planet slowing it down by the same amount that they sped it up by.

> how many people would it take before a day can be shorted by one hour, assuming everyone runs in the same direction for 24 hours straight

Earth has a mass of 6e24kg and rotates  at a speed of 464m/s humans run at an average speed of 5m/s so to reduce the Earth's rotation by 1/24 moving that slowly, your mass of humans would have to be about 1.93e25kg.  Since the average human weighs 62kg, this means you would need 3.12e24 humans. Since Earth has a total landmass of about 5.1e14m^2, that means you would need about 6 billion humans per square meter of land mass. So... there is no way to fit enough humans on Earth to do this.

### But there are other ways to experience a 23 hr day

While moving West could slow down the Earth's rotation, moving East is a much easier way to shorten your day to 23 hours and the best part is, you don't need to organize 3.12e24 people to do it. As I said before, the Earth rotates at 464m/s; so, if you start traveling East along the equator at sunrise at a speed of ~19.3m/s then; then, you will experience the next sun rise in 23 hours giving your a 23 hour day... but people cant run at 19.3m/s.  We also can not maintains speeds of 5 m/s for 23 hours straight.  If you assume we are talking about a normal, but physically fit human, you are looking at being able to cover up to about 30km in a day.  This means you need to circle the Earth where its circumference is less than 720km. But this is not a problem because the farther away from the equator you are, the smaller the Earth's circumference becomes.  So as long as you are within about 1 degree of either the North or South pole, you should be able walk far enough to shorten your day by 1 hour.  That said, days become very much relative that far north.  You will move a time zone; so, technically you have a 23hr day, but that far north, the sun only rises and sets with the seasons, not the rotations of the Earth.

Comment: If you're that close to a pole, wouldn't you'd experience roughly a 8760h day, no matter how fast you walk?

Comment: @AndreasHultgren If you're very close to a pole, because the Earth's spin isn't perfectly in line with its path around the sun, you'll experience winters with a night which is extremely long, and summers with a day which is extremely long. That is, at one point in the summer the sun will rise and stay above the horizon for much longer than 24h, and at some point in the winter the sun will set and stay below the horizon for much longer than 24h. The length of those long nights and days will differ by your proximity to the Earth's rotational pole.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the astonishing amount of energy required to significantly speed up or slow down Earth rotation, running on the planet to speed it up is the same as sitting in sail boat and blowing on the sail to make it move: it doesn't work because it's an internal force, and internal forces, and the resulting of all internal forces is always null. And at no point would your subjects be capable of leaving the planet or not stopping.

Comment: @ths: Not sure that’s true. Angular momentum is a conserved quantity. Consider the case of two equally weighted plates with a line engraved on the edge of both. When you start a motor in between the plates both plates will spin, but when you want to stop one plate moving you *must* steal angular momentum back from the other plate to do so. In other words: you can change the angular momentum of the planet this way as long as the people *never, ever stop running*.

Comment: Also, [you _can_ move a sailboat by blowing into the sail](https://mythresults.com/blow-your-own-sail), because in that particular situation, you're taking ambient air outside of the sailboat/blower system, pushing it against the sail, and the sail can bounce that air backwards outside of the system again.

Comment: I think there are more similarities to the Falling Cat problem. With the translational problem, you can't move the center of mass while keeping zero net momentum at all times. This is unlike the rotational problem, where you *can* rotate while keeping net zero angular momentum. I think you may be able to do some interesting things by running on an angled "straight line" path that spirals from the equator to the pole.

Comment: Agree with @JoeBloggs. Put in other words: on a sail boat it won't work, because the reaction force of your fan is pushing you and your boat backward with the same force. You are attached to the boat, by sitting in it. A running person however puts pressure to another object's surface (Earth) in a certain angle, using friction to move forward. This will change Earth's angular momentum opposite to that direction. The runner uses Earth to propel himself forward, action=reaction in terms of momentum. *How much*.. see Glorfindel's answer.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: They’re pretty much the same actually. The crucial part is that you split the system in two. If you consider the two disks and use polar co-ordinates you’ll see there’s no way to have both disks rotate and still have the lines match up without both disks being away from their original co-ordinates by 180 degrees, which is analogous to having two masses connected by an expanding piston. Thanks to rotation being non-Euclidean you can ‘continue in a straight line’ and end up back where you started, but the same laws apply to both linear and angular mechanics.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [the answer given by another,](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/219106/59924) since the difference is eleven orders of magnitude, it would take 100 billion ish seconds, or around 3000 years.

You'll need to transport the humans back into place somehow, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: your answer is the calculation of every human doing 4 more revolutions per second than the last second. and keeping that acceleration up for that 3000 years.

Comment: The path to slowing the rotation of the planet is not easy, simply necessary.

Comment: "it would take 100 billion ish seconds, or around 3000 years." False. If you keep spinning with constant rotational velocity, you don't get to add _more_ moment of inertia - you'd be in the same situation after the first second as you'd be after 3000 years.

Comment: i don't understand your comment (Napene Nep). what i do know is that acceleration is the thing that can affect the rotational speed of the earth. Something constant speed would never be able to do.

Comment: I mentioned that you would need to transport the humans back somehow, so letting them accelerate constantly is certainly possible.